# Extremely slow download speed in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, performance, internet-speed

I usually use Ubuntu but currently, I am trying to setup Jupyter notebook and PyTorch on Windows. The problem is that while downloading various packages, the download speed is extremely slow (seen below)

> (myenv) C:\Users\hp1>pip install jupyterlab
>
> Collecting jupyterlab
>
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/9b/6ae6e7d844a4ccbb01eaf7b156eceef11562a8379980946009798caa8890/jupyterlab-1.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.4MB)
>
> ```
>  |███████████████████             | 3.7MB 8.8kB/s eta 0:05:00
> ```

However, I have a decent internet connection (quick speed test reveals ~20Mbps download speed). Moreover, the same problem does not occur while downloading packages using terminal in Ubuntu. Can anyone please explain what is causing the bottleneck in the package installation using command prompt?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment on Ubuntu as well? Try using a different terminal.

Comment: Yes, I am using a virtual env on Ubuntu as well. I have tried performing the same installation in a different instance of command prompt, but the problem still persists.